# Is present or past perfect tense choice correct?

Tags: american-english

I'm one of ESL students, Pervasive Developmental Disorder English learner.
I had stayed for a month in Los Angeles since I was 17.
Our native-English teacher at the PDD support school told us that grammatical mistakes in English usage will kill the writing credibility.

for example
Incorrect 
I was working there for 10 years.
I'm living in the United States for 5 years.
I was staying in Los Angeles to study English when I was 17.

Correct
I had worked there for 10 years.
I have lived for 5 years in the United States.
I had stayed and studied English in Los Angeles since I was 17.

Our teacher said present and past perfect tense choice are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected version:

I had worked there for 10 years [another country]. I have lived for 5 years in the United States [as of now]. I have stayed [or lived] in LA and studied English there since I was 17. [if you are still there now].

present perfect [or present perfect continuous] should be used with **since** and **for**:

I've waited for ten minutes. [or have been waiting]

I've lived in LA since I was 17. [or have been living]

The only time you would use: "I had stayed in LA and studied English there since I was 17" is if you moved away.

Like this: "I had lived in LA and studied English there since I was 17. But then, we moved to Hawai, and I did not return."

Compare that to: "**I lived in LA until I was 1**7 and then moved to Hawai".

The "had stayed and studied" refers to time **before moving to Hawai** which you are explaining in the past tense (moved to Hawai).

Comment: but can we say I lived in  LA  studied english  since I was 17  and then moved to Hawai and did not return  as the story respect the chronologycal  order of the action so past perfect is perhaps not necessary

Comment: I lived [simple past] in LA **until** I was 17. There is no **since** in that sentence if you want to use the simple past.

Comment: "since" as a conjunction is usually used in present or past perfect tense, and I was reached in LA.